# Would you know the weight capacity of a roof for a pool house aprox. 400sq ft used as an entertainment space ie. furniture, garden pots, hottub etc.?

Tags: wood, framing, roof, construction, stucco

We would like to have the ideal weight capacity for anything thrown at us basically. If we have to rent out the house the added benefit should be a roof top that can hold additional people, furniture, your average heavy garden pots probably an awning or umbrella. The thing is even if you tell people the capacity they WILL go over that. So I want the structure to prepared for the worst. We are replacing the roof for a flat roof and replacing at least 2 walls. What should we be asking them to install to match the potential capacity load? Thanks

Comment: I would be careful with the hot tub weight

Comment: Sorry it is sq ft.

Comment: Here's another consideration.  Sorta segues with your plan. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifQ4LO3d77Q

Comment: Harper, yeah it does. We are SUPER lucky however we have ZERO snow, rain yes snow no. We are in Northern Ca. and our regions is basically the classic Mediterranean climate soil etc.. I knew it had to be above 60 but how much above 60 to be safe. We could be talking people jumping up and down at full capacity. I just want to be really safe if lots of pots with heavy soil water logged stuff is up there. Basically If I wanted to turn it into a garden oasis it would be fine. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I would build it *as if* it were a second floor. In other words, pretend the structure was a two-story building, it just happens to be that there are no walls and roof on the second floor. If it can handle the load of a normal second floor - furniture, people, etc. plus walls and roof, then it can handle all of that without the walls and roof.

Two other keys for a livable roof:

- Drainage - a flat roof can easily pool water. Plus the materials used to make a flat roof are not necessarily compatible with people, furniture (chair and table legs and other things that could poke through a roof membrane), etc. One possible solution is to build a "normal" flat roof (slight slope for drainage, whatever appropriate materials for waterproofing, etc.) and build a deck (no slope, drains water between the boards) on top of it.
- Railing - This has been a [requirement in Jewish law](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1215/good-fences-make-good-home-owners/) for thousands of years, but I am sure you will find it in the building code somewhere. Basically the same as a railing around any deck that is more than a couple of feet above the ground. Make sure it is sturdy to handle a crowd of people, tall enough to prevent accidents (can't stop someone from *deliberately* climbing over) and gaps small enough to avoid danger with small children.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! :) Yes we're planning on making sure that grade is sloped & there is drainage access. In your opinion is taping off the joists on the roof with Zip tape etc. help with repelling moisture if there was a leak? Is that something a framer would normally do for a rooftop deck before putting the roof on or is that overkill? Also I was gearing toward Marine plywood Vs. OSB since it is sooo close to the pool and water exposure. I want to make the roof as water tight as we can make it.  For the main wall framing and roof framing is there a wood preference? thx

Comment: If we skip the hot tub that came up in comments on the question but not in the question, 40-50 pounds per square foot is a typical (residential) live-load figure for people and furniture. Might want to raise it (or the dead loading) a bit for "heavy garden planters" though. If you're planning for hugely crowded party scene might want to look at commercial live loadings.

Comment: In all the answers and comments I did not see mention of determination if the foundation can carry the extra weight.  The footers may be minimal based only on there being a roof over the walls.  Re framing to hold extra live and dead weight may be something the foundation was not designed to do, especially since this was a pool house.

Comment: Very likely a slab on grade, and even with the weakest of typical soils below those will carry 2000 lbs per square foot. With better soils easily twice that much. Anyway, it's up to the designers to design appropriately or hire an engineer to determine that the design is appropriate.

Comment: Yes it is a concrete foundation floor, under that the typical Sacramento soil rocky and hard basically like concrete when wet, then dried.  The soil is loamy underneath that layer about 3-4 feet + down. The Framing is right on top of the concrete floor slab. Would a framing contractor know what to do?

Comment: In our jurisdiction, the code for a deck is more severe than a normal indoor floor.  The reasoning is that a deck can hold more standing people than a room (with furniture would)